# Rails - New line character at the end of row in CSV import causing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rake

I'm running a rake task to import some file attributes and I'm receiving an error that would lead me to believe that the string created for each line contains some sort of new-line character (e.g. `/n`).

**EDIT** - New-line character has been confirmed to be the issue.

Here is a sample of what my CSV file might look like:

```
1|type1,type2|category1
2|type2|category1,category2,category3
3|type2,type4|category3,category8
```

And here is my code to deal with it:

```
namespace :data do
  desc "import"
  task :import => :environment do
    file = File.open(Rails.root.join('lib/assets/data.csv'), 'r')
    file.each do |line|
      attrs = line.split("|")
      foo = Model.find(attrs[0])

      attrs[1].split(",").each do |type|
        foo.add_type!(ModelType.find_by_name(type))
      end

      attrs[2].split(",").each do |category|
        foo.categorize!(ModelCategory.find_by_name(category))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`ModelType` and `ModelCategory` are both seperate models with a `:through` relationship to `Model` that is built with the function `Model.add_type!` and `Model.categorize!`.

When I run `rake data:import`, everything works fine up until the final `category` is reached at the end of the first line. It doesn't matter which category it is, nor how many categories are present in `attrs[2]` - it only fails on the last one. This is the error I receive:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this or avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use chomp:

```
attrs = line.chomp.split("|")
```

Comment: Had the same problem earlier today. I used a different approach and get rid of all the new lines with File.new('path_to_file').readlines.map(&:chomp)

Answer (score 0):

```
attrs = line.split("|")
if attrs.length > 0
  foo = Model.find(attrs[0])
  ...
end
```

You probably have an empty line at the end of your CSV

UPDATE

```
file = File.open(Rails.root.join('lib/assets/data.csv'), 'r')
file.split("\r\n").each do |line|
```

or

```
file = File.open(Rails.root.join('lib/assets/data.csv'), 'r')
file.split("\r").each do |line|
```

or

```
file = File.open(Rails.root.join('lib/assets/data.csv'), 'r')
file.split("\n").each do |line|
```

depending on how the CSV was originally generated!

Comment: I don't believe it's getting to the end. With the example shown in my question, it would work with `add_type!` on `type1` and `type2`, however I'd receive an error at `category1` and it would not even get to the second line. This is why I believe there is some sort of end-of-line character causing an error with `ModelCategory.find_by_name(category)` because it may be searching for `category1\n` which would return `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.encode(universal_newline: true)` instead gsub.
It converting CRLF and CR to LF # Always break lines with \n